# Stored Procedure not execute as expected

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have written following stored procedure

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[findUSerID]
    @Column_name varchar(50),
    @TR_ID int
AS
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT ' +@Column_name+ ' 
                                  FROM Transfer_TB 
                                  WHERE TID =' + CAST(@TR_ID AS VARCHAR(10))

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Table definition :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transfer_TB]
(
    [TID] [int] NULL,
    [ABC] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [XYZ] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LMN] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [PQR] [varchar](50) NULL,
)
```

But it does not return the proper output.

Like I have called it from my asp page code for that using n tier architecture.

```
public string check_validID(string branch,int trId)
{
    string user_Br_ID;
    clsBranch_TB objbr = new clsBranch_TB();
    clsUserTB objuser = new clsUserTB();
    objuser.User_Branch = 'XYZ';
    objuser.Extra_Int = 32;

    DataSet ds = clsAdminLogic.findUSerID(objuser);

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        user_Br_ID = clsAdminLogic.getno_of_Emp(objbr);
    }
    else 
    {
        user_Br_ID = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
    }

    return user_Br_ID;
}

 public static DataSet findUSerID(clsUserTB objuser)
 {
        DataSet ds = DataAccessLayer.clsLogs.findUSerID(objuser);
        return ds;
 }

 public static DataSet findUSerID(clsUserTB objuser)
 {
     SqlParameter[] param = {
                              new SqlParameter("@TR_ID",objuser.Extra_Int),
                              new SqlParameter("@Column_name",objuser.User_Branch)
                            };
     DataSet ds = DataAccessLayer.SqlHelper.FillDataNewRJ(
                     DataAccessLayer.clsDataAccessLayer.con.ConnectionString.ToString(),
                     CommandType.StoredProcedure, "findUSerID", (param)
            );
     return ds;
}
```

As it executes it, there is value present in database, but still it enters into if part of that function.

Please help me and guide if something wrong in above code

Comment: could you show the design of table structure??

Comment: @ChetanBodke what are you checking in if condition and what is expected ?

Comment: ok first you declare the variable in sql and then set the dynamic query and then execute it , i hope u understand  and also print the query and see whether it is working or not

Comment: just checking that for selected column is there any TID present or not .. there is value for particular column but it shows that there is nothing @KhurramAli

Comment: @dazzlingkumar yes exactly but don't understand whats wrong eith that

Comment: @ChetanBodke you should check that...... Rows are present into the table or not 
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count >= 0)
{
        user_Br_ID = clsAdminLogic.getno_of_Emp(objbr);
}

Comment: show me the printed output of the query

Comment: So you encapsulate the logic inside a stored procedure but still manage to open it up to SQL Injection, but you talk about N-tier architecture...hmm enough said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution for this problem, actually that particular record contains values instead of selective column that's why query returning the null value.
So i just have added one condition my stored procedure to fix it .

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[findUSerID]
@Column_name varchar(50),
@TR_ID int

AS

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT ' +@Column_name+ ' 
FROM Transfer_TB where TID =' + CAST(@TR_ID AS VARCHAR(10))+' 
and '+@Column_name+'<> null'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 2):

Your stored procedure is prone to Sql-Injection. do the following to protect yourself against it.

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[findUSerID]
   @Column_name SYSNAME
  ,@TR_ID       INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

  SET @sql = N' SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@Column_name) 
           + N' FROM Transfer_TB '
           + N' WHERE TID = @TR_ID '

  exec sp_executesql @sql
                    ,N'@TR_ID int'
                    ,@TR_ID 

END
```

If your Stored procedure is returning a scalar value "UserID" as the name suggest you should be doing something like......

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[findUSerID]
   @Column_name SYSNAME
  ,@TR_ID       INT
  ,@UserID      INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

  SET @sql = N' SELECT @UserID =  ' + QUOTENAME(@Column_name) 
           + N' FROM Transfer_TB '
           + N' WHERE TID = @TR_ID '

exec sp_executesql @sql
                  ,N'@TR_ID int , @UserID INT OUTPUT'
                  ,@TR_ID 
                  ,@UserID OUTPUT

END
```

Comment: You can't help some people I'm afraid, even when you try to help they miss the bigger picture. To fixated on getting a resolution to what they believe the problem to be.

Answer (score 0):

> > there is value present in database, but still it enters into else part of that function

I assume this is the part you're talking about (there are *3* functions in that code)

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
{
    user_Br_ID = clsAdminLogic.getno_of_Emp(objbr);
}
else 
{
    user_Br_ID = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
}
```

Yes. Your `if` goes into the `else` if the rows are *not* 0. It's doing exactly what its being told. That basic logic error is the least of your worries though. You're storing branches as columns?